# changing parent_id on post

Tags: posts, filters

I'm trying to change a post's parent via the wp_insert_post_data filter but I'm not having any luck. In the example below, I'm replacing any "parent" references with the id I want to set.

```
function my_insert_post_data($data, $postarr){

    $data["post_parent"] = 123;
    $postarr["parent_id"] = 123;
    $postarr["post_parent"] = 123;

    error_log(print_r($data,true));
    error_log(print_r($postarr,true));

}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'my_insert_post_data' , '99', 2 );
```

and when i log the objects, i see the properties have been set but that never gets written to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make it working you need to return updated data:

```
function my_insert_post_data($data, $postarr){
    $data["post_parent"] = 123;
    $postarr["parent_id"] = 123;
    $postarr["post_parent"] = 123;

    error_log(print_r($data,true));
    error_log(print_r($postarr,true));

    return $data;
}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'my_insert_post_data' , 99, 2 );
```

Comment: @Eugene, What if you wanted to change the $postarr's tax_input>post_tag. In that case, what do we do? How do we return both the $data and $postarr? In my case, I update values in both variables...